# Implementing WPF MVVM Dialog Service

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to implement the "MVVM recommended" way of handling multiple views/windows in the application thru a DialogService. However, I encountered a difficulty in implementing closing the parent view after showing the child view. Here's my implementation so far. What is the best strategy for WPF MVVM to handle such scenario?

DialogService.cs (I try to make this generic so that it can show and close any windows)

```
public class DialogService : IDialogService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Closes the specified window screen
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dialogWindow"></param>
    public void CloseDialog(Window dialogWindow)
    {
        if ( dialogWindow != null )
            dialogWindow.Close ( );       
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Shows the specified window screen
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dialogWindow"></param>
    public void ShowDialog(Window dialogWindow)
    {
        if ( dialogWindow != null )
            dialogWindow.ShowDialog ( );
    }
}
```

The view model that shows the child view is SelectPackageViewModel.cs

```
public SelectPackageViewModel(IPackageDataService packageDataService, IDialogService dialogService)
{
    this.packageDataService = packageDataService;
    this.dialogService = dialogService;
    LoadPackages();
    LoadCommands();
}
private void LoadCommands()
{
    CreateNewCommand = new CustomCommand(CreateNewPackage);
}
private void CreateNewPackage(object obj)
{            
    dialogService.ShowDialog(new CreatePackage());            
}
```

The parent view SelectPackage.cs. The child view is CreatePackage.cs

```
<Button Name="btnNewPackage"
    Content="New..."
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    Width="120"
    Height="30"
    FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold"
    Margin="10"
    Command="{Binding CreateNewCommand}"/>
```

Comment: The "recommended" way for MVVM is that _ViewModels know nothing about the UI_.  That includes indirection via sneaky dialog services

Comment: research mediator pattern and how it can be applied with WPF and MVVM

Comment: Creating a window in a view model breaks the MVVM pattern and defeats the entire purpose of using a dialog service.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always use the NuGet package called MvvmDialogs, or look at its implementation. After all It's open source on GitHub.

Friendly advice, be aware of answers regarding MVVM that are absolute. These answers often come from developers in the learning phase, where rules and guidelines are followed without understanding their benefit. As you progress you start to question "why", and become more pragmatic. The idea that the view model shouldn't be aware of a view service is just silly. It is a view model, the view is in it's name.

Comment: Thanks for the advise! I'll definitely check out MvvmDialogs. In the mean time, I found the following which works pretty well. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47482755/wpf-mvvm-close-window)

Comment: -1 for the second, poorly-advised paragraph.  By using the service method `ShowDialog(Window dialogWindow)` my **MyApp.ViewModels.dll** now has a **direct dependency on WPF assemblies** (namely to resolve `Window`).  The view model assembly has **tight coupling** to presentation types.  Also, because it is such a bad design, what's stopping the VM from showing the window it just created via `CreatePackage` and ignoring the service completely?  This will have a cascading effect. This advice comes from a developer having completed his _"learning phase"_.

Comment: You are not specific enough in your comment. You are referring generally to all dialogs services since you use the plural form of "service". Regarding the dialogs service implemented by the op I agree with you, but I disagree with your general statement. If you re-read your comment you see that you don't help the op at all, you just tell him or her what not to do.

Comment: The OP may want to swim in shark-infested waters because there are those that tell him it's all propaganda.   If I tell him that it's better to swim in a swimming pool instead, surely that will _"help the op"_.   QED

Comment: There's no need to vote down my question. I merely seek advise. Perhaps this question is not for those bloated with ego.